# NEXT.js Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; #423;

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When typing these codes in the page.tsx, in dev mode, it's ok. But after building, the page won't show the {tag.name} and throw two error: `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418;` and `Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423;`
I hope someone to help me know why.
My NEXT.js version: 13.4.12

```
'use client'

export default function Home() {
  const untag = { id: 'untag', name: 'General' }

  const columns = [

    {
      title: 'Time',
      dataIndex: 'time',
      fixed: 'left',
      width: 140,
    },
    ...([untag].map((tag) => {
      return {
        title: tag.name,
      }
    })
    ),
  ]
  console.log('columns', columns)
  return <div>

    {
      [untag].map((tag) => {
        return <div key={tag.name}>
          <span>{tag.name}</span>
        </div>
      })
    }

  </div>
}
```

I try to replace the untag to {...untag} and will resolve the problem. But I'm still puzzled as to why the error was thrown.

Comment: React rehydration errors (uncaught error: minified React error #423 and #418) happen when the client render doesn't match the server render. This can happen when using SSR or SSG, often done with Gatsby or Next. js

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export function BaseShell({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsClient(true);
    }, []);
    return isClient ? (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    ) : null;
}
```

```
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

import BaseShell from './BaseShell';

const inter = Inter({
    subsets: ['latin'],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'your webapp',
    description: 'your platform',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang='pt-br'>
            <head>
                <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no' />
            </head>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <BaseShell>
                    {children}
                </BaseShell>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```